# Flutter Firebase upload multiple images

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

Uploading multiple images and waiting for the URL list, images were loaded to firestore successfully after few seconds and returns the url but before that the future function returns with null

```
Future<List<dynamic>> uploadImage() async {
     _imageFile.forEach((image) async {
      String rannum = Uuid().v1();
      StorageReference reference =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Reviews').child(rannum);
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(image);
      StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl = (await uploadTask.onComplete);
      String _url = await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL();
      _urllist.add(_url);
    });

    return _urllist;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your function like this:

```
uploadImage(_imageFile).then((List<String> urls) => urls.forEach((element) => print(element)))
```

And I also changed your function:

```
Future<List<String>> uploadImage(List<File> _imageFile) async {
    List<String> _urllist = [];
    await _imageFile.forEach((image) async {
      String rannum = Uuid().v1();
      StorageReference reference =
      FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('Reviews').child(rannum);
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(image);
      StorageTaskSnapshot downloadUrl = await uploadTask.onComplete;
      String _url = await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL();
      _urllist.add(_url);
    });

    return _urllist;
  }
```

also I don't understand why you enclosed with brackets "await uploadTask.onComplete"

Comment: Thanks, i tried your suggestion, it is not working. Still receiving blank list

Comment: Yes you have to store your download urls as String not Dynaminc, I updated my answer

Comment: I tried this option, still i am facing the same issue. On multiple image upload, the function is not waiting for all the download URLs. I have changed the function with future.delayed.

Comment: Can you post how you call this Future? Because it's a Future it's async and you have to await for the answer

Comment: I am using the .then as    uploadImage().then((photourl) {}

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: This does not work for me. I still upload a blank url field

Comment: @MAA I think you're facing a different issue, please open another question.